# How to access to my DataBase in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

```
I try this query 
Insert into mining structure [Bike Buyer]
    (
       [Customer Key],
       [Age],
       [Bike Buyer] ,
       [Commute Distance],
       [Education],
       [Gender],
       [House Owner Flag],
       [Marital Status],
       [Number Cars Owned],
       [Number Children At Home],
       [Occupation],
       [Region],
       [Total Children],
       [Yearly Income]
       )
       OPENQUERY ([AdventureWorks2008R2],

        'SELECT [CustomerKey],[Age],[BikeBuyer],

        [CommuteDistance],[EnglishEducation],

        [Gender],[HouseOwnerFlag],

        [MaritalStatus],[NumberCarsOwned],

        [NumberChildrenAtHome],[EnglishOccupation],

        [Region],[TotalChildren],[YearlyIncome]

        FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail]'

    )
```

But I have this Erorr

> Either the 'mta-PC\mta' user does not have permission to access the 'AdventureWorks2008R2' object, or the object does not exist.

Comment: the query isn't being evaluated yet, the problem is not in the code you listed; but rather the connection to the database.  you don't have an open connection, the connection is invalid, or the username/password used to authenticate to the database lacks the permissions needed to do an insert.

Comment: @xQbert How can i have av open  connection?

Comment: Your error message indicates you simply don't have access or there is no database on the server called AdventureWorks2008R2.  As that's the current default database on MSSQL SR2 installs now, I'm betting the user mta in domain mta-PC doesn't have access to the SQL server, you either need to configure the database such that the user mta has permissions; or you need to use a different username when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've encountered this error, it's been because I set the name of the object referenced in the OpenQuery to the name of the relational database or linked server. It has to be set to the name of the Data Source object on the SSAS server. For example, if you have a database that is named AdventureWorks2008R2 that resides on a linked server named MyLinkedServer, but your Analysis Server accesses the data through a Data Source named MyADWorksDataSource, you'd use a statement like OPENQUERY ([MyADWorksDataSource] etc. It's counterintuitive but it works. See Raymond Li's reply to [this thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4db892d9-0c34-4aef-a4f3-2ce18989a3c1/dmx-insert-openquery-permission-problem?forum=sqldatamining). Also see [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095246/mdx-permission-error-when-i-call-a-table-in-sql-server-instance), where the same problem is the culprit.