# MDX permission error when I call a table in SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I am trying to execute this query in MDX

```
INSERT INTO MINING STRUCTURE [People1]
([CustID], [Name], [Gender], [Age], [CarMake],[CarModel])
OPENQUERY(Chapter3Data,
'SELECT [Key], Name, Gender, Age, CarMake, CarModel
FROM People')
```

I have a database `Chapter3Data` with `people` table in my SQL Server instance, but I get this error :

> Executing the query ...
>   Either the 'Ehsan\ehsan akbar' user does not have permission to access the 'Chapter3Data' object, or the object does not exist.
>   Execution complete

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid `mdx`:

```
SELECT [Key], Name, Gender, Age, CarMake, CarModel
FROM People
```

You need to specify which axis you would like the hierarchies `ON` - so generally `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` - an example might be:

```
SELECT 
   [Key].[Key].MEMBERS ON ROWS, 
   [Gender].[Gender].MEMBERS ON COLUMS
FROM People;
```

In SSMS you should be able to open with a connection to the cube server - then you can open an mdx query and test your mdx to ensure it is valid - a good idea before attempting the linked server `OPENQUERY` function.

Comment: This is actually a valid DMX query; the question should be tagged as DMX, not MDX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should be linking to the name of a Data Source defined on that instance of Analysis Services, not a relational database, or the name of a linked server, or a data source view (DSV). I made all three of those mistakes before finally getting it right, after stumbling on to Raymond Li's answer to the post titled D[MX INSERT Openquery Permission Problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4db892d9-0c34-4aef-a4f3-2ce18989a3c1/dmx-insert-openquery-permission-problem?forum=sqldatamining) at MSDN. It's definitely counterintuitive of Microsoft to implement it this way, since you'd plug in a database or linked server any other time you use OPENQUERY, but that's what works.